# Rotating non square matrix in javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix

Im trying to find a way to transform a rectangular matrix by 90 degree.

E.g:

rotate this:

[image: Array 0 degeree]

to this:

[image: Array 90 degrees]

I got an array of indices like that:

```
array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0];
width = 5;
height = 3;
```

Thats what I want to get:

```
array90 = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0];
```

Thanks in regard

Comment: Can you please explain what you've tried so far and where you got stuck ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transform a rectangular matrix by 90 degrees in JavaScript, you can use the following approach:

First, transpose the matrix by swapping its rows and columns. Then, reverse the order of the rows to obtain the 90-degree rotated matrix.

Here's an implementation of this approach and an example:

```js
   //This function takes a rectangular matrix as its input and returns the rotated matrix
             function rotateMatrix(matrix) {
          const rows = matrix.length;
          const cols = matrix[0].length;

          // Transpose the matrix
          const transposedMatrix = [];
          for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            const row = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
              row.push(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            transposedMatrix.push(row);
          }

          // Reverse the rows
          for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            transposedMatrix[i].reverse();
          }

          return transposedMatrix;
        }

            //This example rotates a 3x3 matrix by 90 degrees. The output is the rotated matrix, where the rows are in reverse order.

                const matrix = [
                  [0,0,0,0,0],
                  [0,1,1,1,0],
                  [0,0,0,0,0],

                ];

                const rotated = rotateMatrix(matrix);

                console.log(rotated);
```

Tell me if you are facing any problems.

Comment: But this only works with square matrices, isnt it?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry for this mistake. I edit the answer.

Comment: If the matrix is non-square, meaning it has different numbers of rows and columns, you can still use the same approach to rotate the matrix by 90 degrees. However, the resulting matrix will have a different number of rows and columns.

This function takes a rectangular matrix as its input and returns the rotated matrix. The implementation is similar to the previous approach, but we create a new matrix to store the transposed matrix instead of modifying the input matrix directly.